# .htaccess IP address whitelist not working, still receive 403 forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403

A corporate client has IP address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32`

I've added the following to `/wp-admin/.htaccess`:

```
order deny,allow
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32
deny from all
```

However, when an employee on the corporate network accesses `www.example.com/wp-admin`, they receive a `403 forbidden` error.

If they visit www.whatismyip.com, they're told their IP address is the same as above.

Help appreciated.

EDIT:

`www.example.com/.htaccess` also contains the following:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should go in order because 'deny from all' is the last rule in your example. Try this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 111.111.111.111
```